# How am I able to create a var that just runs one time or already exists before the ForEach Loop?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I've Created a ForEach loop, and now I need a var that already exists before the ForEach loop. I've placed the var inside the struct of the basic view.

I've tried things like `@State` but the thing is that will result in a delay with redefining the variable. So the ForEach loop runs before the variable has changed.

```
 @State var Bol:Bool = true

    var DatesThatAreNewer = Date()



    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                ForEach(self.dayActivities, id: \.self){dayActivity -> AnyView in
                    //NewDays(day: dayActivity.date!)
                    let isNewDay = (dayActivity.date!, formatter: ContentView.self.Day)


                    if self.Bol{
                        let DatesThatAreNewer = Date()
                    }

                    let oldDateType = self.Bol ? (self.OldDate.asDate, formatter: ContentView.self.Day) : (self.DatesThatAreNewer, formatter: ContentView.self.Day)
                    //var isOldDate = (oldDateType, formatter: ContentView.self.Day)

                    print("------------- S1")
                    print(asStringDate(date: dayActivity.date!))
                    print(asStringDate(date: self.DatesThatAreNewer))
                    print("-------------")
                    self.Bol = false
                    if (asStringDate(date: dayActivity.date!) == asStringDate(date: self.DatesThatAreNewer)){
                        print("Hello world 1")
                        print(oldDateType)
                        print(isNewDay)
                        return AnyView(DayActivityView(name: dayActivity.name!, date: dayActivity.date!))
                    }else{
                        print("Hello world 2")
                        print(oldDateType)
                        print(isNewDay)
                        print(dayActivity.name!)
                        DatesThatAreNewer = dayActivity.date!
                        print(asStringDate(date: self.DatesThatAreNewer))
                        //isOldDate = isNewDay
                        return AnyView(Section(header: Text(String(asString(date: dayActivity.date!)))){
                                DayActivityView(name: dayActivity.name!, date: dayActivity.date!)
                        })                        //create seperator and DayActivityView
                    }

                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Dag activiteiten"))
            .navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton(),trailing:
            NavigationLink(destination: ActivityAanmakenView()) {
                Text("Toevoegen")
            })
        }
    }
```

(Excuse me for the many print objects)

So basically I'm looking for a way to redefine the var DatesThatAreNewer, because now it says it's immutable, and if I add a `@State` a delay occurs and the code isn't working anymore as expected.

Comment: Somehow you trigger this view to be shown - why don't you set the date in this trigger (e.g. EnvironmentVariable) and then you have the datesareNewer.....

Comment: There is a lot of information missing from this question. Can you update your question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Currently it is not possible to run your code, so the ability for anyone to provide meaningful help is limited. Please provide all models, functions, and data that would allow the above code to run. The question is also not clear what the end result should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it myself, you just should place the var outside of the struct object.